# Is this valid ISO8601 string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, python-datetime, epoch, iso8601

`2012-12-11T00:00:00+00:00`

One of the AWS service returned error for this

```
ErrorMessage    Attribute submission-date is an invalid ISO 8601 String
```

Code I used to convert epoch time to ISO 8601 is below:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(<epochTimeHere>, timezone.utc).isoformat()
```

Comment: yes, according to [the wiki on ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (see also [ISO/TC154N](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020085148/https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-2.pdf), p.29). But maybe the aws service expects `Z` instead of `+00:00`? (just do a string replace if so, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418))

Comment: Please let me know which service returned the error so I can let the team know that this may be a potentially misleading error message.

Comment: @DennisTraub it is AWS Kendra. Error reported while indexing the files.

Comment: @MrFuppes I did string replacement to come up with something like `2012-12-11T12:00:00.000Z` and it was accepted. (FWIW I am not concerned about hours/minutes/seconds in this particular use case)

Comment: Yes. I think the error message is misleading and have already relayed it to the Kendra team. Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 1):

***Yes,*** a format like `2012-12-11T00:00:00+00:00` is ***specified by ISO 8601*** - see e.g. [wikipedia/ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or [C.4.2 Date and Time](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020085148/https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-2.pdf) of ISO/TC154N, p.29.

From the comment section, it seems however that the AWS service (Kendra) expects a `Z` for UTC (see also [Kendra docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/CommonParameters.html))
, instead of `+00:00` as returned by the Python code. A simple work-around can be a string-replace:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(<epochTimeHere>, timezone.utc).isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
```

---

Side note - Python offers a catch in the other direction as well, i.e. when parsing ISO 8601 timestamps: the built-in `datetime.fromisoformat` method [won't parse `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418) to UTC, but only `+00:00`.